# What's AWS S3 GET byte range maximum offset?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to find this information but without much luck so far.

I have a fairly large file on S3(in a range of 64-128Gb) and I would like to read random byte ranges from it - is it doable? I guess byte-range offset would be very large for chunks somewhere close to the end of the file.

Typical read chunks are 1-12 Kb if that's important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't be a problem.

The [Amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#API_GetObject_RequestSyntax) state that the `Range` header as supported as per spec (but only one range per request):

> Range
>
> Downloads the specified range bytes of an object. For more information about the HTTP Range header, see https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35

[RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) doesn't define any upper limit.

> The first-byte-pos value in a byte-range-spec gives the byte-offset of the first byte in a range. The last-byte-pos value gives the byte-offset of the last byte in the range; that is, the byte positions specified are inclusive. Byte offsets start at zero.

This makes sense because the range is automatically limited by the file size, and a system that, say, only supports 32-bit numbers overall will usually also only support files up to a size of 2 GiB (minus one).

[The maximum size of objects in S3 is 5 TiB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/qfacts.html).